# Separate text in a Textbox with a drawn line?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, split, separator

So here it goes, I making a c# project in wpf and im stuck at trying to make a text box with a line that separates text.

At the moment i got the textbox like this:

[image]

Instead of using "-------" i want to make a predefined line in the textbox. Is this possible ?

Agg. The textbox is editable in runtime

The drawn line should have the properties:

- It should not be edit able !
- It shouldn't only be an empty line
- It should be a visible line that has the width `line.width = box.width` !

Comment: Split text?  What does that mean?  Split based on what?  Two parts?  That is three parts.

Comment: What I ment was a black line separating the text in the textbox.
In this case two separating lines

Comment: @user1735774 why not listbox?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Im using the textbox in an ObservableCollection. And the textbox is numbered so i can undo/redo etc.

Comment: You should be able to do what you want with a listbox and an ObservableCollection. It's your view object that should be handling the undo, not the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need a full textbox implementation then this might help. It's got real issues with not showing the cursor ect but might give you a start.

[image]

first add the following converter to your project.

```
public class TextLineConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    static TextLineConverter converter;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] results = null;
        string newText = value as string;
        if (newText != null)
        {
            results = newText.Split('\r');
            if (results.Length > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
                    if (results[i].Length > 0)
                        if (results[i][0] == '\n')
                            results[i] = results[i].Substring(1, results[i].Length - 1);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (converter == null) converter = new TextLineConverter();
        return converter;
    }

    public TextLineConverter()
    {
    }
}
```

And the following style.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" BorderBrush="Black" >
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <ListView Focusable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Text, Converter={local:TextLineConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

On rereading your question, i believe that the best way to do what you want is to create your own user-control that has an attribute specifically for this. Do some research on C# User Controls and perhaps you'll find out how to do this.

Comment: hehe, that was not what I was looking for but a smart and simple answer i must say.. 
I want to "draw" a visible black line at the location of "-----".
\n \n just makes an "empty" line.